# Adjust insets of UISearchController's searchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying out some designs and I'd like to have an equal 25px margin for all my subviews. `UISearchController`'s `searchBar` has a 16px padding on either sides out of the box. Do I have to write the search bar textfield from scratch, or is there ANY way, undocumented, swizzling, or otherwise, to accomplish offsetting the native bar to my taste?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using a `UISearchController` you can set the margins of the searchBar like this (assuming `searchBar` is the `UISearchController` instance):

```
let directionalMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 25, bottom: 0, trailing: 25)
searchController.searchBar.directionalLayoutMargins = directionalMargins
```

Comment: Thanks, cleaner than mine! I'd just use an implicit init to avoid the word bomb though. (`searchController.searchBar.directionalLayoutMargins = .init(top: 0.0, leading: 25.0, bottom: 0.0, trailing: 25.0)`)

Comment: And as of iOS 13, this is broken again. Thanks, Apple.

Comment: Did you find solution to fix it in iOS 13?

Comment: Actually, it is working for me in iOS13 (using leading and trailing only). Why do you say it is broken?

Answer (score 2):

For `UISearchBar` text position use:

```
searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = .init(horizontal: 25, vertical: 0)
```